# ¿Como hacer una función que hace una consulta sql que varía sobre las valores de un array?

Tags: sql, python

Con el siguiente input (que esta el output de una función Python) :

> ```
> >>> res
>
>                              ids
> grupos                           
> 0                      [296, 306]
> 1       [160, 161, 365, 386, 471]
> ```

Deseo utilizar un output de una función Python para hacer una consulta SQL que hace un COUNT de los `swipe.eclipse_id` sobre los id de un mismo grupo sobre una tabla.

Mi pregunta espesifica esta como hacer para introducir los ids en la consulta SQL. ¿ Con una bolce ? Pero mia me da un " OR " demasiado.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
cur = conn.cursor()

 listado = [None]*len(res)
# on stock les hashtags qui decrivent le mieux les groupes
# on itere sur les gens d'un groupe pour creer la liste du WHERE
#print "res : ", res.iloc[[0]]
for i in (0,len(res)):        
    print "res[i:p] : ", res.iloc[i]['ids']
    cur.execute("""SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id  FROM subscriber_hashtag
    -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
    -- join para que los usarios  estan vinculados con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
    -- recobremos los "me gusta"
    WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
    GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",(res.iloc[i]['ids']))

    n = cur.fetchall()
    listado[i] = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1]} for elem in n]
```

#### Ejemplo :

Aqui esta un ejemplo para el ejemplo minimal y suficiente :

```
subscriber_id hashtag_id
160 345
160 347
161 345
160 334
161 347
306 325
296 362
306 324
296 326
161 322
160 322
```

El output debería ser, mas o menos, de la forma que piensen ser la mas útil :

```
{0:[324,1],[325,1],[326,1],[362,1], 1 : [345,2],[347,2],[334,1]}
```

#### Error :

```
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 50))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f7c3c5b81303> in <module>()
     39         WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
     40         GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
---> 41             ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",(res.iloc[i]['ids']))
     42 
     43         n = cur.fetchall()

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

#### repaso de la respuesta

Tengo un error sobre el recorriendo la lista :

```
query = '''
SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id  
FROM subscriber_hashtag
-- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
-- join para que los usarios  estan vinculados con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
-- recobremos los "me gusta"
WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;
'''
params = [', '.join([str(i) for i in res.iloc[i]['ids']])]
cur.execute(query, params)
listado[i] = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1]} for elem in n]
print listado
```

Tal vez ...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está pasando es que estás tratando de usar un solo parámetro en esta parte de tu query:

```
....
WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
....
```

Sin embargo, lo más probable es que `res.iloc[i]['ids']` contenga más de un elemento (una lista de IDs). Lo que podrías intentar, tal vez, es pasarlo todo como una cadena de IDs separados por coma. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> ids = [10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> '%s' % (', '.join([str(i) for i in res.iloc[i]['ids']])
'10, 20, 30, 40'
```

Para plasmarlo en tu caso, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
query = '''
    SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id  
    FROM subscriber_hashtag
    -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
    -- join para que los usarios  estan vinculados con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
    LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
    -- recobremos los "me gusta"
    WHERE subscriber_hastag.subscriber_id in (%s)
    GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;
'''
params = [
    ', '.join([str(i) for i in res.iloc[i]['ids']])
]
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: Muhcas gracias, sin embargo no tengo el resultado espaerado. ienso que esta un problema sobre el recorrido del array porque `res` esta un 2-tupla

Answer (score 0):

Este codigo compila, pero ne sé si funciona porque da un resultado unico y no resultados diferente con cada usario.

```
listado = [None]*len(res)
    # on stock les hashtags qui decrivent le mieux les groupes
    # on itere sur les gens d'un groupe pour creer la liste du WHERE
    # Go
    for i, ids in enumerate(res['ids']):
        cur.execute("""--- hashtag qui décrivent le mieux les groupes
        SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), 
        subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
        FROM subscriber_hashtag
        INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
        WHERE (swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9) AND subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id in %s
        GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
            ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",
        (tuple(res.iloc[i]['ids']),))
    n = cur.fetchall()
    print "n : "
    print n
```

El output :

```
[(1500L, 996), (1185L, 592), (480L, 1214), (432L, 329), (375L, 398), (306L, 357), (300L, 473), (288L, 325), (225L, 322), (207L, 321), (207L, 1385), (195L, 1445), (180L, 1049), (108L, 334), (105L, 1183), (90L, 387), (81L, 324), (75L, 617), (72L, 379), (63L, 1331), (54L, 2546), (54L, 2545), (48L, 961), (48L, 962), (45L, 1382), (30L, 1432), (30L, 1429), (27L, 1334), (24L, 1128), (18L, 1376), (18L, 386), (18L, 1345), (18L, 1335), (9L, 1354), (9L, 1356), (9L, 1355), (9L, 1357), (9L, 1361), (9L, 1364), (9L, 1374), (9L, 1375), (9L, 1373)]
```